# Raycast a 3D pointcloud to an 2D image from a given viewpoint

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

What I want to do is to raycast a pointcloud to a 2D image. What I have is a 3D PointCloud and a Viewpoint which is different to the general world coordinate system. I would like to raycast from this Viewpoint to generate a 2D image of the point cloud. So, I just need a method like getintersectedvoxel which is doing the casting for the whole area and not only for a single ray.

Comment: something like doing a projection of the points to a plane with the plane normal ?

Comment: You might a look at VTK (http://www.vtk.org/vtkindex.html)

Comment: i got an transformation matrix between the two viewpoints, if this is necessary..

Comment: yeah, in general a projection of the points to a given plane

Answer (score 0):

That is a projection from 3D to a camera. You can get it with the pinhole camera model equations (as shown [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)).

You need first 3 parameters that define your camera: the focal length `f`, and the center of the projection plane: `cx`, `cy`. With this you create a 3x3 matrix (I will use matlab syntax):

```
A = [ f 0 cx;
      0 f cy;
      0 0  1 ];
```

You can use something like `cx = 0.5 * image_width`, `cy = 0.5 * image_height`, and some value as `f = 800` (try some of them to check how the image looks better).

Then, a 3x4 matrix with the transformation from the camera frame to the point cloud frame (you say you have it):

```
T = [ r11 r12 r13 tx;
      r21 r22 r23 ty;
      r31 r32 r33 tz ];
```

And finally, your point cloud in homogeneous coordinates, i.e. in a 4xN matrix for a point cloud with N points:

```
P = [ x1 x2 ... xN;
      y1 y2 ... yN;
      z1 z2 ... zN;
       1  1 ...  1 ];
```

Now you can project the points:

```
S = A * T * P;
```

`S` is a 3xN matrix where the pixel coordinates of each i-th 3D point are:

```
x = S(1, i) / S(3, i);
y = S(2, i) / S(3, i);
```

Comment: thats it in general... but i just want to see the first intersected voxel and not all of the voxels